# Maximum amount of uniforms and or uniform data size in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, memory, shader

I am trying to decide whether to use  a uniform array or an SSBO for a shader I am working on.

I suspect I will need up to a maximum of a thousand textures and up to a thousand vec4 locations.

Would a uniform be able to handle this much data or should I switch to SSBOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenGL spec guarantees that UBOs can be up to 16KB in size (implementations can allow them to be bigger) and that SSBOs can be up to 128MB. Most implementations will let you use SSBOs sized up to the limits of GPU memory.

Personally I'd go with the above guaranteed limits when deciding rather than querying the implementation.

Comment: Does this mean I can have up to 256 `uniform mat4x4` in a single shader program? My research shows people complaining about their code crapping out around 30. What's going on?

Comment: Use glGetIntegerv with GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS, GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS, and GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS, etc. to find out what it is if you're concerned about limits.

Comment: It reports `4096` for `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS`. Is this agnostic to the component's size? Will 4096 `int`s cause me to reach that limit the same way that 4096 `mat4x4`s will, even though a `mat4x4` is 16 times as much data as an `int`? Is this the only limiting factor?

Comment: No, it's not related to component size.   See derhass answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927204/gl-max-vertex-uniform-components-and-component-sizes