# GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS and component sizes

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

As far as I understand `glGet()` with `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` returns the maximum number of available uniform components.

Is there an indicator, how large these components can be (1 byte? 4 bytes?)? Can I address more than `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` components if the components are used with low precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question now is: Is there an indicator, how large these components can be ( 1 byte? 4 bytes? )?

No. A component is just a component of a vector, no matter the data type.

> Can I address more than `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` components if the components are used with low precision?

No.

You *might* be able to *manually* pack multiple data elements into a component, for example 4 bytes or 2 shorts into one 32 Bit integer (assuming your implementation supports 32Bit integers, OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations are not required to). Modern GLSL also has functions like [`unpackHalf2x16`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/unpackHalf2x16.xhtml), so you can pack two half-precision floats into one 32 Bit `uint` component.

Another option to consider (alternatively or additionally to manual packing) is using [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), which allow to specify larger amounts of uniform data.

Comment: So the idea is that if, say, I pack a color into a 32 bit int I can send glget ( GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS ) of them to the shader but if I provide it as a vec4 I can only provide glget( GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS) / 4  , is that right?

Comment: Yes. But since you tagged this quesiton both as opengl and opengl-es, and did not specify which versions you use, it is unclear if the packing strategy is viable. It won't work in ES2.

Comment: Version is GLES 3.1.

Comment: ES3.1 is fine regarding that. You have native 32 Bit integers, bitwise operations, the `pack`/`unpack` functions, and also support for UBOs.